# Using python random.choice in combination with list.append()

Tags: python, random, append

Lately, I've had some problems with Python's `random.choice` function.
I would expect the example script I've added to print out a list that consists of 3 items. Each of those items should be a list that contains two integers and one string.

For example: `[[1, 4, 'a'], [2, 1, 'b'], [3, 4, 'c']]`

```
from random import choice

pair = [
[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],
[2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4],
[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4],
[4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]
]

list = [0, 0, 0]

list[0] = choice(pair)
list[0].append('a')
list[1] = choice(pair)
list[1].append('b')
list[2] = choice(pair)
list[2].append('c')

print(list)
```

Most of the times the script works as expected. Sometimes however, it prints out something like this:

`[[3, 2, 'a', 'c'], [4, 3, 'b'], [3, 2, 'a', 'c']]`

Two of the items in the list not only consist of one string too many, but they are identical for some reason.
First I believed this had something to do with the `append` function.
However when I removed the `random.choice` component like this:

```
list = [0, 0, 0]
list[0] = [1, 2]
list[0].append('a')
list[1] = [2, 3]
list[1].append('b')
list[2] = [3, 4]
list[2].append('c')

print(list)
```

It still worked without flaws.
Same for the `random.choice` function, which didn't cause any problems by itself:

```
from random import choice

pair = [
[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],
[2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4],
[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4],
[3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3],

list = [0, 0, 0]

list[0] = choice(pair)
list[1] = choice(pair)
list[3] = choice(pair)

print(list)
```

Next I tested what would happen when the list contained only one item and `list.append` and `random.choice` were only executed once

```
from random import choice

pair = [
[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],
[2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4],
[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4],
[4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]
]

list = [0]

list[0] = choice(pair)
list.append('a')

print(list)
```

This script behaved like I'd expect as well. Apparently my problem only occurs when `random.choice` and `list.append` are used executed several times on different items in a list, however I don't know how to explain it. Could someone explain what's happening and how to solve it?

Comment: You are placing the pairs themselves in your list.  When you then append to them, you are permanently modifying them; if the same pair is randomly chosen later, it will already have one letter appended to it.  One solution would be to put copies of the pairs in your list before modifying them: `list[0] = choice(pair)[:]` for example.

Comment: for the first example, I cannot reproduce the issue (and I'm relieved). I get `[[3, 2, 'a'], [2, 3, 'b'], [2, 1, 'c']]`. `choice` returns a different list each time. Can you create a shorter [mcve] with expected output and real output?

Answer (score 0):

First I open the REPL prompt and run your first block of code

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> 
>>> pair = [
... [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4],
... [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4],
... [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4],
... [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]
... ]
>>> 
>>> list = [0, 0, 0]
>>> 
>>> list[0] = choice(pair)
>>> list[0].append('a')
>>> list[1] = choice(pair)
>>> list[1].append('b')
>>> list[2] = choice(pair)
>>> list[2].append('c')
>>> 
>>> print(list)
[[4, 1, 'a'], [3, 4, 'b'], [1, 2, 'c']]
```

Looks ok, but what happens if you inspect `pair`

```
>>> pair
[[1, 2, 'c'], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4, 'b'], [4, 1, 'a'], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

So by appending to the lists that `choice(pair)` returns, you have inadvertently modified `pair`.

This is because `choice(pair)` doesn't copy the sublist.

If you mean to make a copy of the sublist, use

```
list[0] = choice(pair)[:]
```

or

```
list[0] = choice(pair).copy()
```